# Customize BIRT "Export Report" dialogue box

Tags: birt

In Export Report dialogue box, we want to provide a new option "Choose XSLT" if user selects "Export Format" as XML.

How to customize this dialogue box?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be customized in a JSP page:

*[birt app root]/webcontent/birt/pages/dialog/ExportReportDialogFragment.jsp*

However the emitter probaly needs to be customized too to take this new input into consideration

Comment: Thanks @Dominique. That's the file which we were looking for !